# Doubt in proving uniform convergence of a Dirichlet series in analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol and I have a doubt in proof of a theorem. I am adding it's image.
[image]

> I have doubt in 4 th line of proof where Apostol writes  the convergence is also uniform for all t.
>
> Is convergence uniform due to the fact that Both of terms in product in  RHS  of 3 rd line are absolutely convergent and hence the Terms on RHS becomes constant and hence independent of t.
> Am I right?

If I am wrong, can someone please give correct explanation for deducing uniform convergence for the product?

Comment: I'm adding this is a comment since it's been a while since I've done undergrad analysis, but I believe the convergence is uniform because the right side of line 3 doesn't depend on $t$. You can have uniform convergence without absolute convergence, and vice versa.

Comment: @Thoth is correct. The RHS does not depend on $t$, thus the convergence is uniform (on $t$).